# Cannot typeset cyrillic text in italics and bold at the same time using the LinuxLibertine font

Tags: xetex, bold, italic, libertine, cyrillic

I cannot tell if the following is a bug in the LinuxLibertine OTF files
or if it is a bug in XeLaTeX (or both?). The problem is: when I try to typeset
cyrillic text in italic and bold, the glyphs appearantly cannot be found in LinuxLibertine.

I have tried this with
 * my uptodate Arch Linux running TeXLive 2013, using the libertine package from my distribution,
 * the same TeXLive with freshly downloaded OTF files from the LinuxLibertine project,
 * a vanilla TeXLive 2014 as installed from tug.org together with the original Libertine OTF files.

Here is a minimal working example (expecting the OTF files in the current working directory; they can be downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/files/linuxlibertine/5.3.0/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[Path              = /path/to/linuxlibertine/,
             Extension         = .otf,
             BoldFont          = LinLibertine_RB,
             ItalicFont        = LinLibertine_RI,
             BoldItalicFont    = LinLibertine_RBI
            ]{LinLibertine_R}
\raggedright
Regular: положим\\
Bold: \textbf{положим}\\
Italic: \textit{положим}\\
Bold+Italic: \textit{\textbf{положим}}
\end{document}
```

The OTF files come straight out of LinLibertineOTF_5.3.0_2012_07_02.tgz. This is XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2014042815
(TeX Live 2013/Arch Linux). In the last line (Bold+Italic), for each cyrillic glyph
I see something like a crossed out rectangle in the resulting PDF file. (When I use
LuaLatex I see nothing where the Bold+Italic glyphs should appear.)

As I said, I cannot tell if this is a bug in LinuxLibertine or in XeTeX. I would be
happy about any pointers/workarounds, as I wish to have this fixed soon.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Linux Libertine lacks the Cyrillic alphabet in the bold italic font, but it has it in the semibold italic font. So a workaround is to use semibold instead of bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[
  Path              = /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/,
  Extension         = .otf,
  BoldFont          = LinLibertine_RZ,
  ItalicFont        = LinLibertine_RI,
  BoldItalicFont    = LinLibertine_RZI,
]{LinLibertine_R}
\raggedright
Regular: положим\\
Bold: \textbf{положим}\\
Italic: \textit{положим}\\
Bold+Italic: \textit{\textbf{положим}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

Things have changed; with TeX Live 2017, the following document shows bold italic Cyrillic with no special setup. I also added the same with Libertinus Serif (of course, the `\setmainfont` declaration should be given just once, with the preferred font).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\raggedright

Regular: положим\\
Bold: \textbf{положим}\\
Italic: \textit{положим}\\
Bold+Italic: \textit{\textbf{положим}}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

Regular: положим\\
Bold: \textbf{положим}\\
Italic: \textit{положим}\\
Bold+Italic: \textit{\textbf{положим}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Stefan Peev added real Bold Italic Cyrillics to Libertinus Serif. So the latest version has them. But mind that Semibold Italic is still buggy placeholders (as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187704/cannot-typeset-cyrillic-text-in-italics-and-bold-at-the-same-time-using-the-linu/187706#187706))

So you either shoud make sure that semibolds are not used or use [Linus Libertini](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/open-fonts/blob/master/README.md#linux-libertine) made specifically for this purpose (that is simply a renamed Libertinus Serif without semibolds).

Comment: So how would you do this in LaTeX? What do you mean by a 'fall back font' in LaTeX?

Comment: Actually, Linux Libertine (and the derivative Libertinus Serif ) are not stylistically equivalent to to Times New Roman. Liberation Serif is a substitute for TNR, I believe. The Libertine/us fonts have a more book-like shape, especially for the lowercase letters, so they are better suited to being an alternative to (very roughly) Garamond-style fonts. As for "fall back font," that would be done using the kind of code shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: @RobtAll I agree. I meant substitutes in metrical sense not stilistical (at least partial metrical compatibility).

Comment: @cfr I guess the simplest way in LaTeX would be swap the whole italics and bold-italics (latin also) from PT Astra Serif (in this case you can use the accepted answer). Or you can fine tune fallback manually. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323575/how-can-i-specify-a-chain-of-fallback-fonts-in-xelatex) for details.

Comment: @RobtAll That's not defining a 'fall back font' in LaTeX's or TeX's sense. (Unless you mean that loading `fontspec` does this, by setting it to LM rather than CM and, of course, for a different encoding.)