# Square brackets with BibLatex in text and bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, brackets

I have read many related posts regarding the issue of having squared brackets with biblatex. Unfortunately, none have made me fully understand how to compute the squared brackets. I know that biblatex is not compatible with natbib, so that was not an option.

This is what it looks like now in the text: 
[image]

This is what it looks like in the bibliography:
[image]

Disered output: I want to have squared brackets instead of the rounded brackets. It seems very simple, but after many frustrating hours I can't figure it out.

This is what it looks in code:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex} % Adjust bibliography style
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\RN{#1}}
```

---

The MWE.tex file:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENTCLASS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn,twoside]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% itemize with dash
\def\labelitemi{--}

\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font

%
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Makes changes in the text font

\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex} % Adjust bibliography style
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\RN{#1}}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   START DOCUMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART II
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Value-based health care is a health care delivery model that aims to achieve high value for patients, with value defined as health outcomes achieved per dollar spent \cite{porter2010value}.


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\printbibliography


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   END DOCUMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

The bibliography.bib file:

```
@article{porter2010value,
    title={What is value in health care?},
    author={Porter, Michael E},
    journal={New England Journal of Medicine},
    volume={363},
    number={26},
    pages={2477--2481},
    year={2010},
    publisher={Mass Medical Soc}
}
```

Comment: By default `biblatex` will produce square brackets with `style=numeric,` and nothing in the code shown in the question suggests otherwise. Can you please post a *complete* example document that reproduces the output you see. Please test the example document in a new, empty folder to ensure it really reproduces the issue. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: It may just be me, but in the screenshot the brackets around the years "(2010)" look slightly different than the brackets around the citation labels. So I would guess that the font you use simply has square brackets that look a bit more round than usual. So this may not be a `biblatex` issue at all. You may just have to choose a different font with more square square brackets.

Comment: @moewe, I think you are right! Very insightful comment. Is there a smart workaround to fix the braces? Perhaps: Is there a way to keep the main font for the text, and use another font for the bibliography?

Comment: I wouldn't do it, but you can try and access the square bracket character from a different font, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333171/35864. For more specific advice I would need to see a *full* example document (see my first comment).

Comment: @moewe: I added the content of the 'MWE.tex' file, and that of the seperate file 'bibliography.bib' . I hope that works for you.

Comment: I notice that you deleted your follow-up question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510261/35864). I was kind of interested in an answer myself. Any reason why you deleted it (if you don't mind me asking)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out what you get in the MWE are square brackets, but `avant`'s square brackets are a bit round at the ends. You can, however, still see a small difference between round brackets and square brackets – at least when you see them side by side.

Here is a solution to let `biblatex` use the square brackets from Latin Modern Sans. Note that this *only* changes square brackets under `biblatex`'s control and only those that are properly typeset with `\mkbibbrackets` and friends. If you are looking for a solution that also replaces the characters `[` and `]` whenever you type them in, I suggest you ask a new question about that (since it has nothing to do with `biblatex` at all).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage{avant}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\sqqbrackleft}{{\usefont{T1}{lmss}{m}{n}\symbol{91}}}
\newcommand*{\sqqbrackright}{{\usefont{T1}{lmss}{m}{n}\symbol{93}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibleftbracket}{\blx@postpunct\sqqbrackleft}
\renewcommand*{\bibrightbracket}{\blx@postpunct\sqqbrackright\midsentence}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
[square] (round)

\sqqbrackleft square\sqqbrackright

\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: avant with biblatex-controlled square brackets from lmss]

Comment: Thanks for the effort and solution. I upvoted and marked your answer as the correct one. And yes, I would actually want to adjust the brackets also for the text as well. I will be posting a new question.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

if there's no specific need for `biber`. Most of the time, `bibtex8` works fine for me and when it doesn't, I quickly find a solution.

Comment: The `backend` should make absolutely no difference to the issue at hand. This is purely a font (or style) issue which is only controlled by the LaTeX side of things. I would also strongly like to disagree with the statement that there is no specific need to use Biber. Many of `biblatex`'s advanced features only work with Biber. Indeed a while ago BibTeX was designated a legacy backend that is only supported for backwards compatibility and the documentation assumes Biber is used. Unless there are reasons that force you to use BibTeX, I strongly recommend using Biber.

Comment: I agree with moewe. The problem boils down to: Adjust the squared brackets '[' and ']' of the avant font type such that the squared brackets become less roundish. I would like them to look like a regular squared bracket.