# Write real UTF32 in Latex?

Tags: xetex, languages, arabic, japanese, chinese

Is it possible to write a Latex document independent of the input language (Latin, Arabic, Japanese, Hindi)?

I though `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` was there to do exactly that, but for instance Japanese would not appear when mixed with Latin characters. My current solution is importing the necessary language packages like `\usepackage{xeCJK}` for Japanese and `\usepackage{CJK}` for Chinese. Isn't there a way though to define UTF32 and not worry about all the language specific packages like `xeCJK` and `CJK`?

Comment: inputenc is for pdflatex, when using it with xetex it does nothing. Beside this: the problem is not the input but the output: the glyphs are in various fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the hint about `inputenc` and `pdflatex`. What exactly did you mean with the glyphs within various fonts? Did you mean like for Japanese input to take `\usepackage{xeCJK}`?

Comment: (nearly) no font has all glyphs. If you want to write english and japanese you normally will have to switch fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Aw ok. In other words, Latex cannot do real UTF?

Comment: This has nothing to do with utf8. You are still confusing input and output. You must tell xelatex which font to use. See e.g. here for similar discussions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323575/how-can-i-specify-a-chain-of-fallback-fonts-in-xelatex

Comment: Basically, Ulrike says that there is no font that covers all of UTF8/16/32. Fonts only cover parts of it. Therefore you need to specify which font to use for which part

Comment: You presumably do not want to input utf32 input  (very few editors support utf32) xetex and luatex (and pdftex with inputenc) support utf8 but whether or not there is a glyph is not related to the input encoding.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XeTeX does have built in support for UTF-32 (and it could be coded in Lua for luatex)

For example

[image]

was produced from

```
\XeTeXinputencoding UTF-32
XXX\XXXdXXXoXXXcXXXuXXXmXXXeXXXnXXXtXXXcXXXlXXXaXXXsXXXsXXX{XXXaXXXrXXXtXXXiXXXcXXXlXXXeXXX}XXX\XXXbXXXeXXXgXXXiXXXnXXX{XXXdXXXoXXXcXXXuXXXmXXXeXXXnXXXtXXX}XXXhXXXeXXXlXXXlXXXoXXX XXXwXXXoXXXrXXXlXXXdXXX\XXXeXXXnXXXdXXX{XXXdXXXoXXXcXXXuXXXmXXXeXXXnXXXtXXX}
```

in which each `X` was replaced by a 0 byte, ascii null (control -`@`)
(I had to make that replacement to X just to post to this site, as posting null bytes is tricky)

Very few editors support this format. even emacs only supports utf-8 and utf-16 by default, not utf-32.

In UTF-32 every character takes four bytes and so every ascii character is preceded by three zero bytes, this means that (in contrast to UTF-8) it is tricky to switch between UTF-8 and a legacy encoding as the string `\XeTeXinputencoding` is represented by a different byte sequence in UTF-32 than it is in UTF-8 or ASCII.

However UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are file encodings for the same underlying Unicode character set so whichever of the encodings you use, the same characters can be represented. Whether that character is typeset depends not on the file encoding of the source but rather on the font being used. However you specify the code points for Chinese, if the current font is latin modern, you will get missing glyph warnings as Latin modern does not have those characters.

It is possible using fontspec to specify a different font to be used for different ranges of Unicode, but normally in LaTeX you need more than just a font switch, hyphenation and spacing (and other things) are language specific and best controlled by explicit commands in the document (which can then also select a suitable font) so a mechanism that just switches fonts when it finds a missing glyph would  perhaps always produce poor output although at first it might seem an improvement on the current behaviour of no output at all.