# Define font faces fallback with fontspec

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

If a font doesn't contain a specific face, it is substituted by default face (like `\mdseries`), while I want to define a chain of fallbacks, so LaTeX keeps searching for an existing face, until it succeeds, e. g.
`black -> extrabold -> bold -> regular`.

How can I do that?

My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\Warnock}{WarnockPro}

\newfontfamily{\Vollkorn}{Vollkorn}[
    FontFace        =   {black}{n}{*-Black},
]


\begin{document}

    \fontseries{black}\selectfont
    \Vollkorn Hello
    \Warnock World

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323575/how-can-i-specify-a-chain-of-fallback-fonts-in-xelatex (just for some ideas).