# Arabic Fallback Font in Context

Tags: context, arabic

My goal is to write small chuncks of Arabic/Hebrew text (words, paragraphs) within a Latin-alphabet language.

I've been trying to set an Arabic fallback font using various examples from here, but so far results have been subpar (even the parentheses do not work)[image]:

```
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [serif] [Adobe Arabic] [range=arabic,feature=arabic]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [serif] [Minion Pro][features=oldstyle]
%\definefontfallback[mainface][sans][range=arabic]
\setupbodyfont[mainface]
\definefontfeature
   [arabic]
   [mode=node,language=dflt,script=arab,
    init=yes,medi=yes,fina=yes,isol=yes,
    liga=yes,dlig=yes,rlig=yes,clig=yes,
    mark=yes,mkmk=yes,kern=yes,curs=yes]


\define[1]\arabico{\definedfont[name:adobearabic*arabic]\setupalign[r2l]#1}



\starttext
% load the font
{
\definedfont[name:adobearabic*arabic% at 36pt
]
\setupalign[r2l]


ضَرَبَ ضُرِبَ ضَرْبًا(
)
ضَرَبَ ضُرِبَ ضَرْبًا
}
%
%\d{D}

Teste: %font loads, no right-to-left
(ضَرَبَ ضُرِبَ ضَرْبًا)
Teste {\definedfont[name:adobearabic*arabic]\setupalign[r2l]ضَرَبَ ضُرِبَ ضَرْبًا}
%works, but parenthesis doesn't
asdf (\arabico{ضَرَبَ ضُرِبَ ضَرْبًا})


\stoptext
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Can't, have to specify explicit character range for font use, [xetex - How can I specify a chain of fallback fonts in XeLaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323575/how-can-i-specify-a-chain-of-fallback-fonts-in-xelatex)

Comment: @user202729, it's lua-tex (context).

Comment: Okay. (still, context supports other engines too, so you can add both tags into the question)

Comment: @user202729 Everything but LMTX is de facto end of life in ConTeXt. MkII with XeTeX for many years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trial and error, scurrying and browsing the manuals, the documentation, the wiki (whose typescript doesn't even work by default), and this site, I found out the solution myself:

```
\definefallbackfamily[myfamily][serif][Amiri][features=arabic,range=arabic] %range=arabic was luck by analogy
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [serif] [Minion Pro][features=oldstyle]
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [sans] [Myriad Pro][features=oldstyle] % ss = sans serif
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [mono] [Consolas] % tt = teletype
\definefontfamily   [myfamily] [math] [Cambria Math] % 
\setupbodyfont [myfamily,11pt] 
\setupbodyfont[myfamily]
\setupdirections[bidi=global] %not in wiki
\starttext
أهلاً وسهلاً

\language[fr]
Asdf; 134890: a!
\stoptext
```